# Rest web-services with jersey-spring3 and existing Spring application context

Tags: java, spring, rest, jersey-2.0, grizzly

I have an existing Spring application with my own context that gets bootstrapped
from douzens of Spring xml files.
A Grizzly web-server is started to publish Soap services.

Now I would like to also serve Rest requests from the same Grizzly.
I'm using jersey-spring3 but it starts it's own, separate application context from a required
applicationContext.xml.

This is the code that creates the Grizzly HttpServer where Rest and Soap web-services 
are registered:

```
    //rest services
    ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig(
            RestService1.class, //these are 
            RestService2.class //jersey-spring services
    );
    HttpServer httpServer = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create("http://localhost:8080/rest"), resourceConfig, false);

    //soap services
    HttpHandler httpHandler = new JaxwsHandler(mySoapWebService, false);
    httpServer.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(httpHandler, myPath);

    httpServer.start();
```

My Rest services (created by the 2nd Spring context) have injection dependencies from the first app context. 
These injections obviously don't work. Curreetly I'm injecting them myself manually with some hacky code.

What is the correct way to inject Spring services for Rest request handling in an existing application, where 
jersey re-uses the existing context?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [helloworld-spring-annotations](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/helloworld-spring-annotations) from the Jersey project on GitHub. You just need to [set the `"contextConfig"` property](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/examples/helloworld-spring-annotations/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/examples/hello/spring/annotations/App.java#L69) in the Jersey application with the value being the instance of the Spring `ApplicationContext`

```
resourceConfig.property("contextConfig", 
        new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringAnnotationConfig.class));
```

Then you should be able to `@Autowired` your Spring components into your Jersey components.

**See Also:**

- [Combining Spring project and Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32355845/2587435)