# Combining Spring project and Jersey

Tags: java, spring, jersey, jax-rs

I've built a project with Spring JPA, and now I want to use it in my Jersey project.
I've added my SJPA project as a dependency in my pom.xml

I would like to use my service classes from my SJPA when I use GET/POST/PUT/DELETE methods.
Is there an easy way to do this with annotations? Or do I have to get `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` in each class? Feels kind of waste.

```
@Path("/users")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public final class UserResource
{
    private AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    private PodcastService service;

    @GET
    public Response getAllPodcasts() {
        context.scan("org.villy.spring.service");
        context.refresh();
        service= context.getBean(PodcastService.class);
        return Response.ok(service.findAll()).build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**NOTE: The linked example projects below are from the Jersey master branch, which is currently a snapshot of Jersey 3, which is not yet released. Jersey 3 will be using Spring 4, so you may notice a dependency `jersey-spring4`. This dependency does not exist yet, as Jersey 3 is not yet released (probably not for a while). So the dependency to use is `jersey-spring3`. All the example should still work the same, just changing that one dependency. If you want to use Spring 4, see the dependencies listed in the example pom below in this answer**

---

You don't need to create the `ApplicationContext` where you need the service. You should be able to configure a global one. Jersey has a module for this that integrates the two frameworks. This allows you to simply `@Autowired` all your Spring services into your Jersey resource classes.

Instead of trying to produce any example, I will just link to the official examples. They are straight from the projects, so the links should be good for some time. Take special not of the Maven dependencies. You will need to make sure to have them for the example to work.

- [Jersey 2.x with Spring XML config](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/helloworld-spring-webapp)
- [Jersey 2.x with Spring Java config](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/helloworld-spring-annotations) <sup>[**1**]</sup>
- [Jersey 1.x with Spring XML config](https://github.com/jersey/jersey-1.x/tree/master/samples/spring-annotations)
- [Jersey 2.x with Spring Boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-jersey)

<sub>**Note:** The `${spring3.version}` version in the examples is 3.2.3.RELEASE. It's possible to use Spring 4 with the examples, but you will need to make sure to exclude all the Spring transitive dependencies from the `jersey-spring3` dependency.</sub>

[**1**] - One thing to note about the Java config example is that it uses a standalone app. To use Java config in a webapp requires a bit of trickery. This is [a known bug](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2038) where Jersey looks for an param `contextConfigLocation` with the location of the `applicationContext.xml` file and will throw an exception when it doesn't find one.

I've found a few ways around this.

1. An example of this was mentioned by the person who raised the issue. You can create a Spring web initializer where you configure the spring context *and* override the param property. (See full example [here](https://github.com/psamsotha/underdog-jersey-spring-example)).

   ```
   @Order(1)
   public class SpringWebContainerInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

       @Override
       public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
           registerContextLoaderListener(servletContext);

           // Set the Jersey used property to it won't load a ContextLoaderListener
           servletContext.setInitParameter("contextConfigLocation", "");
       }

       private void registerContextLoaderListener(ServletContext servletContext) {
           WebApplicationContext webContext;
           webContext = createWebAplicationContext(SpringAnnotationConfig.class);
           servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(webContext));
       }

       public WebApplicationContext createWebAplicationContext(Class... configClasses) {
           AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context;
           context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
           context.register(configClasses);
           return context;
       }
   }
   ```
2. You could simply add the `applicationContext.xml` to the classpath and just register the spring Java configuration class as a bean

   ```
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


       <context:annotation-config/>
       <bean id="config" class="com.your.pkg.SpringAnnotationConfig"/>

   </beans>
   ```
3. There's another way I can think of, but I've save that for a time I can actually test it out.

---

### UPDATE

> "Failed to read candidate component class ... ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet"

Seems to be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526695/java-1-8-asm-classreader-failed-to-parse-class-file-probably-due-to-a-new-java), using Spring 3 with Java 8. Like I said, if you want to use Spring 4, you will need to exclude the Spring transitive dependencies from `jersey-spring3` and just change the version of your explicitly declared Spring dependencies. Here is an example, that I tested and works.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId> 
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId> 
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId> 
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId> 
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for a well described answer!

I've checked in your examples and using the one with Java config, including the "bug fix".

But I do get in to one wierd exception
"Failed to read candidate component class ... ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet"


Will do try maybe with XML so for now

Comment: Ok so I did some searching, and it looks like [this is the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526695/java-1-8-asm-classreader-failed-to-parse-class-file-probably-due-to-a-new-java). The dependencies are using Spring 3, but it seems that Spring 4 is required for Java 8. So if you want to use Java 8, like I said you should exclude all the transitive dependencies from the `jersey-spring3` dependency and change the Spring version to a 4.x verison. I will post an example,

Comment: I would like to add one more thing!
Got issues with version 4.1.0.RELEASE resulting in: "org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.findPropertyForMethod"

All I did was instead using update to 4.1.5.RELEASE , where I found the answer to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983563/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-springframework-beans-beanutils-findpropertyfor)

Comment: ***"…but you will need to make sure to exclude all the Spring transitive dependencies"*** this could have saved 5h of my life yesterday… Totally overlooked that hint. Thanks!