# jersey 2 + spring 4 + jetty-maven-plugin

Tags: java, spring, maven, jersey, jetty

I am trying to make an example of using jersey 2 + spring 4 + jetty-maven-plugin. But keep getting this error, cannot understand why.. Please give me a hand.

```
WARNING: The Jersey servlet application, named com.joejag.code.orders.restservices.ResourceConfiguration, is not annotated with ApplicationPath and has no servlet mapping.
2015-12-16 19:56:38.746:INFO:/.0-SNAPSHOT:main: Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringWebApplicationInitializer@2776015d]
2015-12-16 19:56:38.778:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@15fb7a32{/orders-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT,file:///home/bryan-1/workspace/project/java/simple-java-restful-service-using-jersey-and-maven-master/src/main/webapp/,STARTING}{file:///home/bryan-1/workspace/project/java/simple-java-restful-service-using-jersey-and-maven-master/src/main/webapp/}
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No such servlet: Example
```

My POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.joejag.code.orders</groupId>
    <artifactId>orders-server</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Example</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jersey.version>2.22.1</jersey.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey + Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring4</artifactId>
            <version>3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>

                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.3.6.v20151106</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanTargets>
                        <scanTarget>${project.basedir}/src/main</scanTarget>
                        <scanTarget>${project.basedir}/src/test</scanTarget>
                    </scanTargets>
                    <webAppConfig>
                        <contextPath>/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</contextPath>
                    </webAppConfig>
                    <contextPath>${project.artifactId}</contextPath>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Example</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.joejag.code.orders.restservices.ResourceConfiguration</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <!-- <init-param> <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.joejag.code.orders.restservices</param-value> </init-param> -->
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Example</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My ResourceConfig class

```
package com.joejag.code.orders.restservices;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

public class ResourceConfiguration extends ResourceConfig {
    public ResourceConfiguration() {
        register(OrdersService.class);
    }

}
```

My applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.joejag.code.orders.restservices" />

    <bean id="transactionBo" class="TransactionBoImpl" />
    <!-- <bean class="OrderService" /> -->
</beans>
```

**EDITED**

after fixing inconsistant `servlet-name` issue Jetty is able to load the servlet, but a new issue arise that all the `@PUT` method seems to no longer execute. Here the OrderService look like.

```
package com.joejag.code.orders.restservices;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

/**
// * curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:8080/orders-server/orders/1?customer_name=bob
// * curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/orders-server/orders/1
 * curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/orders-server/orders/list
 */

@Component
@Path("orders")
public class OrdersService
{
   public static Map<String, String> orders = new TreeMap<String, String>();

   //@Autowired
   //private TransactionBo transactionBo;


   public OrdersService()
   {
       //his.transactionBo = transactionBo;
   }

   @Path("/{order}")
   @PUT
   @Produces("text/html")
   public String create(@PathParam("order") String order, @QueryParam("customer_name") String customerName)
   {
      orders.put(order, customerName);

      return "Added order #" + order ;//+ this.transaction.save();
   }

   @Path("/{order}")
   @GET
   @Produces("text/html")
   public String find(@PathParam("order") String order)
   {
      if (orders.containsKey(order))
         return "<h2>Details on Order #" + order + "</h2><p>Customer name: " + orders.get(order);

      throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
   }

   @Path("/list")
   @GET
   @Produces("text/html")
   public String list()
   {
      String header = "<h2>All Orders</h2>\n";

      header += "<ul>";
      for (Map.Entry<String, String> order : orders.entrySet())
         header += "\n<li>#" + order.getKey() + " for " + order.getValue() + "</li>";

      header += "\n</ul>";

      return header;
   }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you get rid of the `javax.ws.rs.Application` init-param and add `@ApplicationPath("/")` on top of the `ResourceConfiguration`?

Comment: @peeskillet same error output

Comment: What happens if you don't use the jersey-spring4 snapshot, and instead use the jersey-spring3 (2.22.1) and just excluding the spring 3 artifacts, and adding the 4s yourself, as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32357991/2587435). I don't see much wrong, that's why I'm asking. I've never used the new spring4 snapshot, so I 'm just wondering if it's any problem with that

Comment: @peeskillet true. I am going to roll back to what you suggest if it still going no where.

Comment: Does your OrderServices class have @Path at the class level. Can you share the code.

Comment: servlet-name has to be consistant :)

Comment: You should close this question and open a new one for the new problem. What you are doing is not how Stack Overflow works. Glad you solve the issue though. You should post it as an answer, and move on to the next

Answer (score 0):

`servlet-name` in the web.xml has to be consistant. After fixing that jetty is able to load the servlet.