# basic Jersey webservice with maven jetty plugin

Tags: java, maven, jersey-2.0, maven-jetty-plugin

I have been working with the restfull webservices provide by Jersey in combination with the maven jetty plugin at my previous job. But now for a personal project i am starting from scratch by myself and i cant seem to get even the basic version going. I have tried to follow a few tutorial but they are either old or off topic.

The most recent example i tried was:
[jersey 2 + spring 4 + jetty-maven-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34326436/jersey-2-spring-4-jetty-maven-plugin)

So the below configs make the plug in run but no matter which url i try it gives me 404's

pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <groupId>foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <jetty.version>9.3.11.v20160721</jetty.version>
        <jersey.version>2.23.1</jersey.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>test</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.foo.bar</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <!--<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>-->
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

resourceConfiguration.java

```
package com.foo.bar;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

public class ResourceConfiguration extends ResourceConfig {
    public ResourceConfiguration() {
        register(entrypoint.class);
    }

}
```

and my service class

```
package com.foo.bar;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

public class entrypoint {
    @GET
    @Path("/test")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String test() {
        return "it works";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String test2() {
        return "it works";
    }

}
```

Nothing fancy right i feel like this should work out of the box.
The Jetty server starts but like i said i get jetty 404 pages at every url permutation i try.

Thanks in advance for any and all input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few Changes need to be done to make it work. please follow the below steps.

**Step 1:** change your web.xml like below with the POJO mapping and Resourse configuration class instead of package name.

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>bar.com.ravi.ResourceConfiguration</param-value>
        </init-param>
       <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**Step 2:** change your ResourceConfiguration class like below with package information.

```
public class ResourceConfiguration extends ResourceConfig {
    public ResourceConfiguration() {
        packages("bar.com.ravi");
        register(Entrypoint.class);
    }

}
```

**Step 3:** Change your EntryPoint class with Class level @Path Annotation.

```
  import javax.ws.rs.GET;
    import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

    @Path("/hi")
    public class Entrypoint {
        @GET
        @Path("/test")
        @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
        public String test() {
            return "it works";
        }

        @GET
        @Path("/")
        @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
        public String test2() {
            return "it works";
        }

    }
```

**Step 4:** Change your POM.xml in build tag like below.

```
<build>
    <finalName>bar</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.2.11.v20150529</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <webApp>
                        <contextPath>/bar</contextPath>
                    </webApp>
                    <httpConnector>
                        <port>8888</port>
                    </httpConnector>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

**Step 5:** run below command your command promt.

```
mvn jetty:run
```

**Step 6:** hit the browser with below URL

```
http://localhost:8888/bar/hi/test
```

Comment: Thank you so much. For the record the changes that fixed it were as follows: Step 1: was a typeo, my bad
Step 2: adding the package.
Step 3: adding the class level @Path
Step 4: adding the context path.
All others didnt affect the outcome but not doing any of these made the entire thing crumble. funny part is i have tried all of these at one point or another just not all together. *edit the enter button is a funny thing

Answer (score 0):

The obvious thing that is wrong on your configuration is

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.foo.bar</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

I believe this must be

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.foo.bar.ResourceConfiguration</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

then add the package where your resource classes are currently sitting.

```
    <init-param> 
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.foo.bar</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

Comment: Place @Path annotation to your Entrypoint class. e.g. @Path("bar") then hit localhost:8080/bar/test

Comment: Thanks this was also part of the what was wrong, check my comment at the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <webApp>
                    <contextPath>/bar</contextPath>
                </webApp>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

and direct your browser to http://localhost:8080/bar/test, for example.

Comment: This was part of the solution, see my comment at the accepted answer. Thanks for the help