# Loading spring context when web application context loads

Tags: spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, jersey-2.0

I want to use the dependency injection from spring framework in my jersey-rest project?? Is there any other way to load the spring context when my web application context loads other then spring-mvc??

Comment: Look at the [example](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/2.22.2/examples/helloworld-spring-webapp), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32357991/2587435)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a sample code to test this out once. This [GIT link](https://github.com/bandikishores/jersey-springmvc_web_services-logback) has the code for Jersey and Spring integration.