# HK2 Jersey. Way create @Service with env options

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0, hk2

As I see, I can use autosearch annotation `@Service` to create `singleton` to use that via `@Inject`. Like:

```
@Service
class MyService {
    //.....
}

@Service
class MyOtherService {
    @Inject MyService myService;
    //.....
}
```

But would like to create Service using options that depends on environment.
I could do that using `AbstractBinder` like:

```
        final ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig()
            .register(new AbstractBinder() {
                @Override
                protected void configure() {
                    String someOption = "optionOne";
                    String anotherOption = "optionTwo";
                    MyService myService = new MyService.create(someOption, anotherOption);
                    bind(MyService).to(MyService.class).in(Singleton.class);
                }
            })
```

But how can I do just the same but using annotation autoconfig style? Without creating AbstractBinder object.

Comment: Here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/41436316/2587435

Comment: Some more examples https://stackoverflow.com/a/36322902/2587435

Comment: thanks. one more thing here. How can I get bean from container manually? I have a chain of features inside my IoCBinder. And I would like to use dependencies from first feature for another.

Comment: Bindings.service(ConfigurationProvider.class) - shows that I have 0 qualifiers

Comment: Not sure. You might want to post a different question with more information. Seems off topic for this post.