# NullPointerException while using @Autowired in maven webapp

Tags: spring, maven, jersey

I am trying to integrate Jersey with Spring using maven `webapp-archetype`. When I get the object form the ApplicationContext I see my code executing, but when I try to use `@Autowired` it throws me `NullPointerException`. Following are the code snippets:

applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.pack.resource" />
<bean id="person" class="com.pack.resource.Person">
    <property name="name" value="SomeNamexxxx" />
</bean>
```

Person.java

```
package com.pack.resource;

 public class Person {

private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Person() {

}

 }
```

Hello.java

```
package com.pack.resource;

 import javax.ws.rs.GET;
 import javax.ws.rs.Path;
 import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
 import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

 @Component
 @Path("/hello")
 public class Hello {

 @Autowired
 Person person;

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getName() {

    return person.getName();

}
```

}

But when I use `ApplicationContext.getBean("person").getName()` it gives me the actual value inside the bean property.
Why is `@Autowired` annotation not working as it should. Kindly help me.
TIA!

Comment: Can you paste the logs here. It would help understand the problem better.

Comment: Most likely you haven't configured the Jersey/Spring integration correctly. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/32357991/2587435

Comment: Have you added a ContextLoaderListener to your web.xml: `<listener>  
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>  
    </listener> `

Comment: Thanks @zakariaamine worked fine after configuring web.xml

Comment: Thanks @peeskillet the reference helped me