# Configuring Spring RESTFUL API webapp with Java

Tags: java, spring, rest, jersey

I'm having some trouble trying to set up a `RESTFUL API` using `Spring Framework` and `Spring Security` + `Jersey`.

I could deploy a `Jersey` rest api and request resources successfully but when I also implemented Spring (Framework + Spring security) things are getting out of hand.

I've worked before with old `Spring` versions where configuration was made with `XML` files, but I would like to play and learn how to config it with `Java` annotations only. I'm having trouble with this as I can't get past `applicationContext.xml`. I simply don't want to put an `XML` file, I just want to configure my small rest api webapp with `Java` annotations only.

When I added `Spring Security` config lines to my `web.xml` and tried to request any resource, this error appeared:

`No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener or DispatcherServlet registered?`

So, I also added this snippet to my `web.xml`:

```
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Then, I created a new configuration class for Spring, a simple one:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({
    "com.myapp.rest.api", 
    "com.myapp.business.services"
})
public class SpringApplicationConfig {

}
```

I restarted my `Tomcat` again and tried to request any resource, then it started to complain about **not finding** the `applicationContext.xml` file, which I didn't provide, but I don't know why it is still trying to find it if I have another class with `@Configuration` annotation. How can I configure `Spring` without using `applicationContext.xml`?

**Note:** I am aware of `Spring MVC` and `Spring Boot`, but I'm currently playing with `Jersey` and using `Spring Framework` for dependency injection, also `Spring Security` for auth and security stuff obviously.

Below my `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container, 
    see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.myapp.rest.api</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- SPRING SECURITY -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And my `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>api</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>api</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>my api</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- JERSEY (2) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Soporte JSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    <!-- SPRING + SPRING SECURITY -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet-api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JACKSON - JSON -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--  LOG4J2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--  JWT TOKEN -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
            <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>${jose.jwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


    <properties>
        <jose.jwt.version>4.39.2</jose.jwt.version>
        <spring-security.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
        <spring.version>4.3.9.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <log4j.version>2.8.2</log4j.version>
        <jersey.version>2.9.1</jersey.version>
        <jackson.version>2.8.9</jackson.version>
        <servlet-api.version>3.1.0</servlet-api.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32357991/2587435

Comment: @peeskillet got rid of the errors when trying your workaround by creating a dummy applicationContext.xml. I think this could be the answer to this question but some other issues with `Spring Security` configuration arised and I need to solve them first to verify that in fact your answer worked (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some important points in web.xml

```
 // For java config, you don't want to use .xml 
  // you have to include AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
      </param-value>
    </context-param>

    // Location of your Configuration class
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>my.package.AppConfig</param-value>
    </context-param>

    // To load context
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    // Spring Servlet
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringApplication</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
   // Your controllers
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>my.package.controllers.HomeController</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    // Servlet url mapping
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Adding controller class

```
@Component
@Path("/home")
public class HomeController {
```

**UPDATE :**
   As it was told that author of question is interested in just Spring DI, not involving Spring MVC, below is simple config bootstrapping WebApplicationInitializer to configure the ServletContext programmatically, without web.xml. Note that this would require Servlet 3.0+ container.

```
public class ApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)  throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context 
          = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
        servletContext.setInitParameter(
          "contextConfigLocation", "com.package.my");
    }
}
```

Comment: this also worked as http://stackoverflow.com/a/32357991/2587435. Errors are gone but now I need to face some issues with `Spring Security` configuration. Actually I think this is the answer that I was looking for, but I usually get confused when using spring because I don't think it's easy to configure. I only took the `contextClass` and `contextConfigLocation` from your snipped to get it to work, because I'm not using `Spring MVC`, I'm using `Jersey`.
Do you know if with Spring Security is also needed to do something similar to get rid of `applicationContext-security.xml` ?

Comment: I see, I thought MVC might be useful, as you build your project further.

Comment: What do you mean with 'further'? I think I'll give `Spring MVC` a go soon, but right now I need to use `Jersey`

Comment: In my understanding, MVC is core of web project, allowing you to build things up. If you just need Spring DI, it would be different configuration.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but as I only needed a REST API I thought it could be overkill to use a full MVC framework, but I have to admit that it looks easy to configure and get things up running quickly

Comment: I don't think there is a overkill, you need to configure and load servlets anyway. There is no overhead.

Comment: @JorgeGRC I have updated my answer with simple configuration without web.xml