# HK2 Dependency Injection for DeltaSpike Data or Spring Data JPA

Tags: dependency-injection, jersey, spring-data-jpa, hk2, deltaspike

I'm developing Jersey-based RESTful Web Services. And, I'm choosing between DeltaSpike Data and Spring Data JPA for my repository layer. I have tried both of them. I'm amazed that they are almost the same.

DeltaSpike Data:

```
public interface AuthorRepository extends EntityRepository<Author, Long> {
}
```

Spring Data JPA:

```
public interface AuthorRepository extends CrudRepository<Author, Long> {
}
```

But my problem is not as to which one is better and I should choose but, how to apply HK2 dependency injection.

By manually creating AuthorRepository and AuthorRepositoryImpl, I can simply do this configuration:

```
public class ApplicationBinder extends AbstractBinder {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(AuthorRepositoryImpl.class).to(AuthorRepository.class).in(RequestScoped.class);
    }
}
```

But I could not figure out how to apply above similar configuration if I use either DeltaSpike Data or Spring Data JPA since there is not an implementation class for repository interface.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would go with Spring Data, as Jersey/HK2 already has an integration module for Spring. This will allow you to inject any Spring beans into your Jersey resources. And the Spring Data repository being a Spring bean, the injection works seamlessly; no need to configure anything with HK2/Jersey. All you would need to configure is the Data configuration for Spring. To get it working, you need to take the following steps:

#### 1) Add the jersey-spring dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

This will give you the Spring/Jersey integration, allowing you to inject your Spring beans into your Jersey components. See also [Combining Spring project and Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32357991/2587435). It shows some different examples of using both Java configuration an XML configuration.

#### 2) Configure the Spring/Data beans.

This will be your normal configuration, assuming you have done Data configuration with Spring before. This will consist of configuring the JPA vendor, transaction manager, and data source.

#### 3) Inject your repository into your Jersey resource and enjoy.

You can find a complete example in this [**GitHub Repo**](https://github.com/psamsotha/jersey-spring-example)